# ABAQUS meshing problems :The volume of 13124 elements is zero, small, or negative?

Tags: mesh, abaqus, abaqus-odb

I tried to develop a thermal model by using an orphan mesh part(DC3D8R) but when I run the model, the following error was displayed:
**'The volume of 13124 elements is zero, small, or negative. Check coordinates or node numbering, or modify the mesh seed. In the case of a tetrahedron this error may indicate that all nodes are located very nearly in a plane. The elements have been identified in element set ErrElemVolSmallNegZero.'**
Please, how can I fix this error ?
Thank you !